# Incorrect word wrap in labels/pickers

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Sometimes my text in labels or pickers in Android will wrap before the end of a label. It doesn't happen every time, but when it happens the text will initially appear correctly and then quickly rerender incorrectly. This only happens when the views are in a Grid, but I can't be sure that's the cause. Using the "show layout boundaries" option, I can see that the width of the label is correct and doesn't change, it's just the word wrap that doesn't properly.

relevant code in a ContentView subclass constructor:

```
Grid _contentGrid = new Grid()
{
    RowDefinitions = new RowDefinitionCollection()
    {
        new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) },
        new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) },
        new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) },
        new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) },
    },
    ColumnDefinitions = new ColumnDefinitionCollection()
    {
        new ColumnDefinition() { Width = 48 },
        new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
    },
    BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
    Padding = new Thickness(16, 16, 16, 16),
    ColumnSpacing = 16,
    RowSpacing = 8,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
};

Label _questionLabel = new Label()
{
    Text = "Do you want to update the instrument setup?",
    TextColor = Color.FromHex(Colours.TextGrey),
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    XAlign = TextAlignment.Start,
    WidthRequest = 344

};

_contentGrid.Children.Add(_questionLabel, 0, 2, 3, 4);

DialogView dialogView = new DialogView()
{
    TopView = TitleLabel,
    MiddleView = _contentGrid,
    BottomView = ButtonGrid,
    TopColour = Color.FromHex(Colours.Blue),
    MiddleColour = Color.White,
    BottomColour = Color.White,
    MiddleHeight = 150,
};

Grid Holder = new Grid()
{
    ColumnDefinitions = new ColumnDefinitionCollection()
    {
        new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
        new ColumnDefinition() { Width = 368 },
        new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
    },
    RowDefinitions = new RowDefinitionCollection()
    {
        new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
        new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) },
        new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
    },
    BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("b0000000")
};

Holder.Children.Add(dialogView, 1, 1);
this.Content = Holder;
```

The _questionLabel text only shows "Do you want"

Comment: Have you specified a `LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.NoWrap;`

Comment: @Mario Galván I have and it doesn't help. It's as if the text is being laid out with the wrong width. Plus, that doesn't help me with the Picker, which has no LineBreakMode property.

Comment: hmmm maybe it has something to do with tour GridLenth's or LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand, it may be helpful to color all your layouts and views (Labels and pickers), to see which one of those are affecting the Label/picker view.

Comment: That's the thing, there's no other views that could be affecting it. I fixed it by switching to a stacklayout because in this case there was only a single column. It seems to be an issue with Grid's AUTO gridlength. I've had possibly related bugs with labels losing their text alignment if there's a screen update that affects the grid they're in. In every case, somewhere among the parent chain there's a grid doing autosizing